# Push certificate not appearing when creating a profile in iOS dev portal

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I've created a dev push certificate for my app (following these steps http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

and I can see the certificate appearing in the certificates section of the portal.

Now I'm trying to create a provisioning profile which includes the certificate, however  when the portal asks which certificate(s) to include in the profile the one I just created is not listed.

I have triple-checked that the app id I used to create the certificate is the same as the app id I am using to create the profile - and if I examine the app id the green dot has appeared next to the push enabled section.

So why is the certificate not appearing as an option when creating the profile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Provisioning profile certificates are separate from push notification certificates. You probably need to generate a developer certificate instead.

Comment: I already have a developer certificate. If the push certificate is not placed in a profile and the app signed with it then pushes won't work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not supposed to put the push certificate into the profile. The push certificate is placed on your server and is used to authenticate against the apple APNS server (for the server<->server link).

Answer (score 4):

Push certificate is just an SSL certificate for your web server or 3rd party service.  Nothing to do with provisioning.  Just be sure to have the same bundle ID.